# Radius Protocol - How to correctly set the status in the second request?

Tags: java, windows-server-2012, radius, tinyradius

I'm using [TinyRadius](https://github.com/ctran/TinyRadius) to authenticate my Java WebServer (as Radius Client) to a Windows Server (as Radius Server).

I successfully sent the user Access-Request to the server and received the passcode back.

```
final RadiusClient client = new RadiusClient(
    new RadiusEndpoint(
        new InetSocketAddress(RADIUS_SERVER_ADDRESS, PORT),
        SHARED_SECRET
    )
);

final AccessRequest request = new AccessRequest(
    USERNAME,
    USER_PASS
);

request.setAuthProtocol(AccessRequest.AUTH_PAP);
request.addAttribute("NAS-IP-Address", RADIUS_CLIENT_ADDRESS);

RadiusPacket packet = null;

try {
    packet = client.authenticate(request);
} catch (final RadiusException | IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code is followed by a log which states that the user authentication was approved by the server.

```
Sep 29, 2017 10:05:32 AM org.tinyradius.util.RadiusClient authenticate
INFO: send Access-Request packet: Access-Request, ID 1
User-Name: mp
NAS-IP-Address: 192.168.0.58
Sep 29, 2017 10:05:33 AM org.tinyradius.util.RadiusClient authenticate
INFO: received packet: Access-Challenge, ID 1
State: 0x7b41324244344539362d453139332d344539392d413134322d4134423536364441443938437d
Reply-Message: Enter PASSCODE
```

The Event Viewer on my Windows Server, too states that the Access-Request was accepted.

In fact I correctly receive the passcode on my mobile application (I'm using SMS Passcode by Censornet, altought this is irrelevant).

Unfortunately, I could not find any TinyRadius Passcode example on the web, but while browsing for other libraries, I stumbled upon this [python library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-radius), which states that:

> The ChallengeResponse exception has `messages` and `state` attributes `messages` can be displayed to the user to prompt them for their
>   challenge response. `state` must be echoed back as a RADIUS attribute.

and

> Finally authenticate again using the challenge response from the user
>   in place of the password.

So all I did is to use the same code above. I put PASSCODE instead of USER_PASS and I add the state attribute to my AccessRequest.

```
final RadiusAttribute stateAttr  = new RadiusAttribute(24, STATE.getBytes());
request.addAttribute(stateAttr);
```

I send the request to the server and I can see this log.

```
Sep 29, 2017 10:34:04 AM org.tinyradius.util.RadiusClient authenticate
INFO: send Access-Request packet: Access-Request, ID 1
User-Name: mp
NAS-IP-Address: 192.168.0.58
State: 0x307837623431343133353330333433363334333832643433333433343339326433343432343633303264343234343335343532643330343533323337343633383332333333373332333933373764
Sep 29, 2017 10:34:04 AM org.tinyradius.util.RadiusClient authenticate
INFO: received packet: Access-Reject, ID 1
Reply-Message: Session is unknown or has expired
```

The Windows Event Viewer states:

```
Event description:
    Event type:         Authentication request
    Result:             Failure
    Failure reason:     Password validation failed
```

So I read the RFC 2865 Access-Challenge Chapter at Section 4.4, and they state that:

> the receipt of a valid
>         Access-Challenge indicates that a new Access-Request SHOULD be
>         sent [...]
>   with the User-Password Attribute replaced by the
>         user's response (encrypted), and including the State Attribute
>         from the Access-Challenge, if any.  Only 0 or 1 instances of the
>         State Attribute can be present in an Access-Request.

I'm therefore doing everything right, I guess. May anyone help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues in how I was sending the second request to the [radius](/questions/tagged/radius) server.

---

Doing it this way did not work as `STATE.getBytes()` returned a differently-encoded `String`:

```
final RadiusAttribute stateAttr  = new RadiusAttribute(24, STATE.getBytes()); // BAD
request.addAttribute(stateAttr);
```

What I had to do was: first store the response into a new `Packet`.

```
final AccessRequest request = new AccessRequest(
    USERNAME,
    USER_PASS
);
packet = client.authenticate(request);
```

Then, create a new `AccessRequest` for answering the challenge and set the **state** in the following way.

```
final AccessRequest challengeResponseRequest = new AccessRequest(
            USER,
            PASSCODE
);

challengeResponseRequest.addAttribute(
    new RadiusAttribute(24, packet.getAttribute(24).getAttributeData()) // GOOD
);
```

*(Note: 24 is the [attribute code for STATUS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2865#section-5.24))*

---

By sending the newer `AccessRequest`:

```
client.authenticate(challengeResponseRequest);
```

the log confirms the authentication was successful:

```
Sep 29, 2017 2:05:13 PM org.tinyradius.util.RadiusClient authenticate
INFO: received packet: Access-Accept, ID 2
Class: 0x8f8007ad0000013700010200c0a800050000000024db5d173578383201d3379907bd2a500000000000000098
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question - I wish more people would do this when they found out the answer on their own!